# If $AB=BA$ then they are diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw this statement

> If $AB=BA$ then both matrices must be diagonal.

Why is that?

Comment: Pretty sure that's completely wrong...

Comment: This is clearly false, take $A$ arbitrary and $B=A$. There is however, a statement that if $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable and $AB=BA$ then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: You can say that if $A$ and $B$ are diagonal, then $AB = BA$. The implication in one way!

Comment: This maybe relevant, if $A,B$ are diagonizible then they are simultaneous diagonizible if and only if they commute.

Comment: Related as @the_candyman said http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736677/prove-that-ab-ba-if-a-b-are-diagonal-matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $A=I$ and $B$ is a arbitrary matrice then we have $AB=BA$ and maybe $B$ is not diagonal!

Comment: Miss your answwrs here. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like this theorem:

> Suppose that $B$ is diagonal with different values of the diagonal, and $AB=BA$.
>   Then $A$ is diagonal as well.

Proof:

for every $i\neq k$
$$
\sum_{j=1}^d A_{ij}B_{jk} = \sum_{j=1}^d B_{ij}A_{jk} \\
A_{ik}B_{kk} =  B_{ii}A_{ik}
$$
now as $B_{kk}\neq B_{ii}$, then $A_{ik}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that if $A$ and $B$ are diagonal, then $AB = BA$. The implication in one way!

Suppose now that $A$ is not diagonal and take $B = A$. Then:

$$AB = A^2 \text{ and } BA = A^2$$

Hence,

$$AB = BA$$

but $A$ and $B$ are not diagonal!