# Prove that $AB=BA$ if $A, B$ are diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could you confirm my proof?

A fixed Proof (Confirm please):

Let $A, B$ be two diagonal matrices of order $n$. Then, both $AB,BA$ are defined and are of the same order $n$ (i.e. sizes match). Also, $A_{ij},B_{ij}=0$ whenever $i\ne j$.

Consider the case $i\ne j$:
$$\eqalign{
  & {\left( {AB} \right)_{ij}} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{A_{ik}}{B_{kj}}}  = \sum\limits_{i \ne k = j} {{A_{ik}}{B_{kj}}}  + \sum\limits_{i = k \ne j} {{A_{ik}}{B_{kj}}}  + \sum\limits_{i \ne k \ne j} {{A_{ik}}{B_{kj}}}  = \sum\limits_{i \ne k = j} {0 \cdot {B_{kj}}}  + \sum\limits_{i = k \ne j} {{A_{ik}} \cdot 0}  + \sum\limits_{i \ne k \ne j} 0   \cr 
  &  = 0 + 0 + 0 = 0 = \sum\limits_{i = k \ne j} {{B_{ik}} \cdot 0}  + \sum\limits_{i \ne k = j} {0 \cdot {A_{kj}}}  + \sum\limits_{i \ne k \ne j} 0  = \sum\limits_{i = k \ne j} {{B_{ik}} \cdot {A_{kj}}}  + \sum\limits_{i \ne k = j} {{B_{ik}} \cdot {A_{kj}}}  + \sum\limits_{i \ne k \ne j} {{A_{ik}}{B_{kj}}}   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{B_{ik}}{A_{kj}}}  = {\left( {BA} \right)_{ij}} \cr} $$

Consider the case  $i=j$
$$\eqalign{
  & {\left( {AB} \right)_{ij}} = {\left( {AB} \right)_{ii}} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{A_{ik}}{B_{ki}}}  = \sum\limits_{k \ne i} {{A_{ik}}{B_{ki}}}  + \sum\limits_{k = i} {{A_{ik}}{B_{ki}}}  = \sum\limits_{k \ne i} {0 \cdot 0}  + {A_{ii}}{B_{ii}} = 0 + {A_{ii}}{B_{ii}}  \cr 
  &  = 0 + {B_{ii}}{A_{ii}} = \sum\limits_{k \ne i} {0 \cdot 0}  + {B_{ii}}{A_{ii}} = \sum\limits_{k \ne i} {{B_{ik}}{A_{ki}}}  + \sum\limits_{k = i} {{B_{ik}}{A_{ki}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{B_{ik}}{A_{ki}}}  = {\left( {BA} \right)_{ii}} = {\left( {BA} \right)_{ij}} \cr} $$

Hence, corresponding entries are equal.

Thus, $AB=BA$.

Quod Erat Demonstrandum.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The proof is OK but it would be good to prove first that the product of two diagonal matrices is the diagonla matrix obtained by multiplying the elements of the diagonal. Once this done, the result is clear, and you will need this so often after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I d'ont think that your provf is correct. In your proof, you have $(AB)_{ij}=A_{ii}B_{ii}$, clearly it's not correct.
$$(AB)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^nA_{ik}B_{kj}$$
for $k\neq i$, $A_{ik}=0$, and for $k\neq j$, $B_{kj}=0$. So $(AB)_{ij}=A_{ii}B_{ij}+A_{ij}B_{jj}$, then when $i\neq j$, $(AB)_{ij}=A_{ii}*0+0*B_{jj}=0$, and when $i=j=k$, $(AB)_{ij}=(AB)_{kk}=A_{kk}B_{kk}$.

In another hand, you can do the same calculation for $BA$. You will have the same results:
when $i\neq j$, $(BA)_{ij}=B_{ii}*0+0*A_{jj}=0$, and when $i=j=k$, $(BA)_{ij}=(BA)_{kk}=B_{kk}A_{kk}=A_{kk}B_{kk}=(AB)_{ij}$.
So $AB=BA$.

Your proof shows only that when $i=j$,$(AB)_{ij}=(BA)_{ij}$.

Comment: But both matrices are diagonal, so the other terms are zero.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a much quicker proof:

Let $e_n$ be the nth basis vector, $a_n$, $b_n$ the entries of the $n^{th}$ column of $A$, $B$, respectively. Then $$ABe_n=A(b_ne_n)=b_nAe_n=b_na_ne_n=a_nb_ne_n=a_nBe_n=Ba_ne_n=BAe_n\,.$$ Since the matrices agree on all basis vectors, they are equal.

Comment: Simple way is enough!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly correct, though you may want to note that you use the fact that diagonal matrices have a diagonal product. There are cleaner ways to do this, but there aren't any fundamental issues with this one.